# oVirt hosted engine install error: Failed to verify Power Management configuration

Tags: cluster

I am new to ovirt and I am trying to install it on minimal-install CentOS 7.
I have been able to iron out all the wrinkles to create the host-engine, except for this error:

> [ ERROR ] fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The host has been set in non_operational status, deployment errors: code 505: Host myFQDN installation failed. Failed to configure management network on the host., code 9000: Failed to verify Power Management configuration for Host myFQDN., fix accordingly and re-deploy."}

Can someone layout what this issue is all about or point me in the right direction?  I have been battling with this for 2 days now, without any clue on what it is about.